NestJS JSON parser can't handle long numbers
I am trying to parse JSON body in a request but some numbers are parsed as strings, although these numbers appear as numbers (no quotation marks) in the JSON file. It appears to be that long strings are converted to string quietly in the background.
e.g.
{"id": "<someid>", "locations": [{"time_stamp": "2024-04-18T02:35:31+00:00", "latitude": 11.2925537333, "longitude": 6.3405951333333334, "altitude": 152.7, "accuracy": 0.0, "speed": 0.0}]}

Above, longitude will be parsed as a string.
If the number is longer than 14 characters (with the decimal point), that the number appears in the NestJS parsed object as strings. Even though the type is controlled with a DTO, which explicitly expects a numberic value.
Shortening the number resolves the issue.
I wonder, if this is intended to if it is a bug?
  app.use(json({ limit: '2mb' }));

  app.setGlobalPrefix(globalPrefix);
  
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
    transform: true,
    whitelist: true
  }));

